# Dropping row level duplicates from a spark dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I need to drop row level duplicates from a dataset, need to know if `dropduplicate()`  is an expensive operation if my dataset is very large .

If the operation is expensive due to shuffling and all other processes happening in the backend, what is the other efficient way of dropping these row level duplicates?

Comment: Can you add data with code. Why you need to drop?

Comment: My  requirement is  to load  data from some source  files f to database . We are loading the delta of today’s and yesterday’s data . Now the src files that we receive has  a lot of row level duplicates in it. Don’t want to unnecessarily process the duplicates